# Is there a way to access to Samsung's clipboard content programmatically?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, clipboardmanager

As we know, Samsung's devices have their own clipboard that stores all the data you copy or your screenshots.

I want to manage and delete the content programmatically, I tried to use the ClipboardManager API but it does not provide me a way to delete the screenshots, only the text.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.